# jquery getting value from getJSON

Tags: jquery

I;m trying to get the value `'content'` from my json data

**This is the data:**

```
[{"pk": 2, "model": "template", "fields": {"content": "message", "status": "Draft", "user": 16, "name": "test", "created": "2013-05-19T20:59:04Z"}}]
```

**This is what I have tried:**

```
 $.getJSON('/sms/fetch/' + id, function (data) {
           $('#id_content').val($('#id_content').val() + data.fields.content);

        })
```

but this does not seem to get the value, the value is within the call as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a array, so:
`data[0].fields.content`

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` appears to be an array of objects, so you need to access it by index:

```
console.log(data[0].fields.content); // "message"
```